# 9 overlapping images with transparency cause lag

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have 9 images overlapping each other in a `RelativeLayout` (Code below). When I change tabs (Using `Fragments` in a `FragmentActivity`) to this specific tab, it causes a lot of lag. I am assuming that this is because the images are reloaded when the `Tab` changes, resulting in lag?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021background"
        android:id="@+id/background"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021range"
        android:id="@+id/range"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021topography"
        android:id="@+id/topography"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021waterways"
        android:id="@+id/waterways"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021catchments"
        android:id="@+id/catchments"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021wthrdistricts"
        android:id="@+id/wthrdistrics"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021roads"
        android:id="@+id/roads"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021rail"
        android:id="@+id/rail"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/idr021locations"
        android:id="@+id/locations"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a better way to do this, with out causing lag? (Maybe show loading circle and then change to images in `onActivityCreated` of the `Fragment` - Am trying this now)